Create different Variables in a loop
I want to create new variables such as a1, a2, a3, a4, b1, b2, ......h4
I would like to create them automatically, so I do not have to write something like this:
 a1 = 0
I really need help so thanks for your help
this is python btw

I don't why you would need it but here is one way
for x in range(5):
   globals()['a%s' % x] = f'Test{x}'

print(a1)
This is not the best practice, you can try using dic or list

Definitely not best practice. A dictionary would be a better approach.
